# Showing vertical scrollbar always in a textarea field

Tags: css

I need to show a `vertical scrollbar` always in a `textarea` for which I put

```
overflow-y:scroll;
```

Which can then be visualized as shown below,

[image]

although the scrolling element does reflect, but I am amazed at where is the bar which needs to be as shown below. I want like this as shown in the below figure,

[image]

Just need that black bar. Any suggestions.

Comment: The bar isn't there, because you have nowhere to scroll.

Comment: @Marthy: That is my client's requirement to show it always, even when there is nothing to scroll.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although it is not recommended, you can use padding. That way you'll always have a place to scroll to.

```
textarea {
    height: 0px;
    overflow-y:scroll;
    padding-bottom: 200px; /*your height*/
}
```

The text will now always have padding at the bottom though, so you'll be able to scroll past the text content.

Comment: @ShirgillAnsari Please, don't. This is a horrible horrible hack and terrible user experience. Don't give scroll unless there's actually somewhere to scroll to.

Comment: @ShirgillAnsari were you hired as a professional, or as a code monkey? If it's the latter, I seriously suggest you find another company to work in.

Answer (score 8):

The small bar won't be there if you have nowhere to scroll. That's not a behavior you can change.

Tell your client/boss that their requirement is unreasonable.